# How to convet telerik radbarcode to bitmap without missing label?

Tags: c#

I am using Telerik RadBarcode in my Asp.Net web application. See my code to generate the RadBarcode programmatically.

```cs
RadBarcode barcode = new RadBarcode();
barcode.Type = BarcodeType.Code128;
barcode.ID = "RadBarcode1";   
rcode.Text = "656146114";
barcode.ShowText = true;
barcode.OutputType = BarcodeOutputType.SVG_VML;
Bitmap bitmap1 = new Bitmap(barcode.GetImage());
bitmap1.Save("D:\\" + "\\bmap.jpg");
```

While saving the barcode as an image the text under the barcode is missing in my case.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can place a label below the barcode image to show the text and create one new bitmap image which contains the text and barcode data. Refer to the example below;

```
 RadBarcode barcodeRB = new RadBarcode();
        barcodeRB.Type = BarcodeType.Code128;
        barcodeRB.Text ="123456789";          
        barcodeRB.ShowText = true;         
        barcodeRB.OutputType = BarcodeOutputType.SVG_VML;
        Bitmap bitmap1 = new Bitmap(barcodeRB.GetImage());
        System.Drawing.Image image = barcodeRB.GetImage();          
        Bitmap barCanvas = new Bitmap(435, 205);
        barCanvas.SetResolution(90, 90);
        using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(barCanvas))
        using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255)))
        {
            gfx.FillRectangle(brush, 0, 0, 435, 205);
        }
        using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(barCanvas))
        {
            RectangleF rectf = new RectangleF(150, 170, 300, 50);
            gr.DrawImage(image, 20, 20, 400, 150);
            gr.DrawString(studentTest.BarcodeString, new Font("GenericSansSerif", 26), Brushes.Black, rectf);
        }
```

barCanvas.Save("D:\" + "\bmap.jpg");